# How to delete specific users in bulk in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How can WordPress delete users in bulk when the `user_id` is already known?

Is there an easy way to do this? For example `SQL CLI` or `PHP CLI` or something like that. Has anyone already done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the WordPress CLI. There's a user delete command which can accept a list.

Examples from the docs:

```
# Delete user 123 and reassign posts to user 567
$ wp user delete 123 --reassign=567
Success: Removed user 123 from http://example.com

# Delete all contributors and reassign their posts to user 2
$ wp user delete $(wp user list --role=contributor --field=ID) --reassign=2
```

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/delete/

Comment: Testing the above example does remove the user, but I have a question, according to the WP-CLI documentation note, you can use user ID, name or email in the command, so how does WP-CLI differentiate them? Because it is possible that the user ID and name are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet to delete specific users whose ids are known.

```
function delete_specific_users() {

  //Include the user file with the user administration API
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );

  //Get a list of users that belongs to the specified role
  $users = get_users( array( 'ID' => array( comma separated list of user_ids you want to delete ) ) );

  //Delete all the user of the specified role
  foreach ( $users as $user ) {
      wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
  }

}

// call the method like this.
delete_specific_users();
```

Comment: How should I use `delete_specific_users()`? Do I put it in a php file and then access the php file? How do I know if it deleted successfully?

Comment: You can add it to ```functions.php``` or any other php file in your theme. You can confirm it from the admin panel or you can follow this solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165693/179180